# How to run laravel 5.2 artisan command on cron job on hostgator hosting server cpanel?

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5

I have created an example schedule job to run after a specific time in Laravel 5.2. And this is working fine on `localhost` through `artisan` command.

I am running this command on local server:
`php artisan Demo:Cron`

Now I am adding this task in cPanel's advance option cron job on HostGator hosting server. But it is not working.

This is the command I am trying:

`cd /home/pofindia/public_html/beta-var1/ && /usr/local/bin/php artisan Demo:Cron`

Php version: 5.4 default.
And here is my example file

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use DB;

class DemoCron extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'demo:cron';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        DB::table('items')->insert(['name'=>'hello new']);
        $this->info('Demo:Cron Cummand Run successfully!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe run `/usr/local/bin/php /home/pofindia/public_html/beta-var1/artisan Demo:Cron`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it is not working for me. Can there be some problem in setting of cpanel... or getting something  activated from the hosting provider. if yes how to check..

Comment: well then best ask the hostgator guys

Comment: Try to remove `DB` call and leave only `$this->info()`.

Answer (score 3):

run

```
which php
```

to see where the php executable is, copy that path.

```
crontab -e
```

(I'm assuming this is your project root where your artisan is located */home/pofindia/public_html/beta-var1/*  but this requires you to add artisan to it, as so **/home/pofindia/public_html/beta-var1/artisan**)

add the crontab entry

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php  /home/pofindia/public_html/beta-var1/artisan Demo:Cron
```

really all you are doing here is providing the absolute paths

Comment: This answer seems correct to me, and similar to how I would have responded. In order to run a cron job you need to be able to edit the crontab entry on the server using `crontab -e`. Note that crons are run per user so if you are having problems you need to make sure that the user (root, ubuntu, etc.) has access to execute php and artisan commands in their path for the cron entry

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick hack around it that i tested and its working. It will work for a cpanel or other hosting platforms

1. create a route say /mycron and point it to a controller method say 'myCronMethod'.
2. Inside the myCronMethod, call your command as follows

   Artisan::call("cache:clear");

   or your command ie

   Artisan::call("Demo:Cron");

//make sure you use the artisan facade at the top as follows

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
```

3. Then now you can set your cron to be calling the above route you just created ie

*/5 * * * * curl --request GET 'http://myapplication.com/mycron

or

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home/CpanelUsername/public_html/myapplication/mycron

simplified sample
//route

```
Route::get('/mycron', ['uses'=>'MyController@myCronMethod']);
```

//Controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function myCronMethod(){
        Artisan::call("cache:clear");
        Artisan::call("Demo:Cron");
    }

}
```

Comment: thank u for an answer, but i think you don't understand my question. what i'm asking is how i tell the hosting to run my cron job. what is the path i need to set in cron settings

Comment: So how do you intend to call your ``route`` without ``cronjob`` ? @Sweety's problem is she/he can't runing already ``cronjab`` on hosting panel.

Comment: */5 * * * * curl --request GET 'http://myapplication.com/mycron'

or

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home/CpanelUsername/public_html/myapplication/mycron

Answer (score 1):

Seems like in Laravel 5.2 command names are case-sensitive.

I just tried on fresh Laravel 5.2 installation:

```
$ php artisan Demo:Cron

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
There are no commands defined in the "Demo" namespace.          

Did you mean this?                                              
    demo
```

Whereas:

```
$ php artisan demo:cron
Demo:Cron Command Run successfully
```

So, the solution would be to use `demo:cron`, as it defined in command's `$signature`.

Answer (score 0):

Ask HostGator to add a `MAILTO="your@email.com"` to your cron spool.

Then, let it run, and see if it gives you any output errors or otherwise.

If you get an email saying "Demo:Cron Cummand Run successfully!" then you know it works

If you get an email saying otherwise, then report the error via ticket/chat and they should be able to help you fix the PHP/artisan execution.

One thing I might say is to `cd ~/public_html/beta-var1` before your `php artisan demo:cron` call in your cron instead of specifying an absolute path.  Ensure you don't have `&>/dev/null` or anything that hides or redirects STDOUT/STDERR in your cron.  Once you have it working, you can suppress the output by removing the `$this->info();` call

Comment: i already added my email and here is my command
/usr/local/bin/php /home3/username_path/public_html/projectName/artisan user:update
is this good/valid

Answer (score 0):

You can run manually cron job by this artisan command

```
php artisan schedule:run
```